# Django form with autocomplete functionality

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on a django project with complex forms. In one of my form fields I need following functionality...... Its the text field. As the user starts typing the value the suggestions from existing database should appear in dropdown. Can anyone help me out with this ? Just similar to autocomplete but able to add new values.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be something in the JQuery/AJAX side of things, not Django. I would read up on the autocomplete functions of JQuery and use AJAX to call your DJango code and receive a populated list, which then displays to the user.

[JQuery Autocomplete - Custom Data](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with JavaScript, you can use a django application called django-autocomplete-light.

You can learn more about it (and get it) here: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light